# Are there any commercial CFD codes that implement a Discontinuous Galerkin scheme?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, discontinuous-galerkin

I've been reading about the Discontinuous Galerkin discretization scheme and it's application to CFD for fluid flow. It seems to be a promising method for simulating turbulent flows, by using higher-order cells to mitigate the need to have extremely high mesh densities.

I am just wondering if there are any commercial (or free) 'industrial-grade' CFD codes out there that utilize such a scheme? If not, why not?

(by 'industrial-grade', I mean codes that have been developed to the point that a non-expert industrial user would be able to use them for arbitrary problems. E.g. ones that have a simplified GUI interface and/or streamlined workflow that doesn't involve modifying source code)

Answer (score 3):

I believe Numeca is developing a Flux Reconstruction (related to DG) extension of their solver. I am sure other companies are doing so as well.

However, commercial codes have a somewhat different set of requirements than academic codes. Commercial codes target speed and robustness more than accuracy, and both of these are harder to get with DG. I think that is why it will take some time for DG to start being seen in commercial codes.